# Set attributes of node created from template element

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, native-web-component, html-templates

The below code fails with console error `Uncaught TypeError: node.setAttribute is not a function`. How can I change the attributes of nodes created from templates?

```js
const template = document.createElement("template");
template.innerHTML = `<div>hello</div>`;
const node = template.content.cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(node);
node.setAttribute("style", "background-color: green;")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that the clone doesn't return the `div`, it returns a `document-fragment`, using `querySelector` as per below solves this.

```
const template = document.createElement("template");
template.innerHTML = `<div>supppp</div>`;
const node = template.content.cloneNode(true);
node.querySelector("div").setAttribute("style", "background-color: green;");
document.body.appendChild(node);
```

Comment: FYI ``setAttribute`` overwrites all existing styles, to only style the background use: ``node.querySelector("div").style.backgroundColor="green";``